# ¿Porque no me deja crear un metodo seter dentro de una clase de c++?

Tags: c++

Acabo de empezar hace poco con c++ y me está costando un poco.Estoy creando una clase y quiero ponerle un simple metodo seter pero no se porque el compilador me da un error. Estoy seguro de que es una estupidez pero me vendría muy bien que alguien me lo explicara. Este es mi código:

```
class Horario
{
private:

    Byte horas;  
    Byte minutos;

public:

Boolean setHoras(Byte);
};

Boolean Horario::setHoras(Byte entrada)
{

    horas = entrada;

    if (entrada<24||entrada>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

El error que me marca Visual Studio es este: "la declaración no es compatible con (se declara en la línea 53)"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no entiendo .

Comment: Con el codigo que compartes no se reproduce el error. Asumiendo que `Byte` y
`Boolean` sean tipos validos, el codigo compila perfectamente. Estas seguro de
que esta es la parte del codigo que da el problema?

Comment: @Pablochaches he puesto una foto para que veas lo que me pone

Comment: Y si copias solo el codigo que publicaste, y lo pegas en tu editor, te sale el mismo error? Yo ya probe con clang y gcc y ninguno me tiro error.